# Getting Cordova setup for Android - mac

Tags: android, macos, cordova, installation

Trying to get a Phonegap app running for Android.

I downloaded Cordova 3.4 and created a new Android project.

I then tried to import it into eclipse but it had an error with the classpath. I read online that you can copy the .classpath from a project created within eclipse. That solved that issue.

Now when I import it i get config errors. I noticed that when creating the cordova project, it doesnt create the cordova.jar file which is needed in all the tutorial i read online.

```
Config cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved    
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type SecondBirthday must override or implement a supertype method
```

What do i need to do to get this thing running? how do i generate a Cordova.jar file if thats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the missing `cordova.jar` is the issue - as of Cordova 3.3.0, they included Cordova as a separate project to your own: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5232 so there should be a folder called [YourProjectName]-CordovaLib.

Not sure why the classpath error occurred. I would attempt to create a HelloWorld project to start of with, and see where that gets you:

```
$ cordova create Test
$ cd Test
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova build
```

Once that has finished executing, open Eclipse, and import your project - 'File > Import > Existing Android Code Into Workspace' and then your project will be imported.

It should build automatically, but I always like to clean the project - 'Project > Clean... > OK' - just in case the cordova script misses something.

You should be able to run this.

Also, what is your code for `SecondBirthday` doing? This might be a separate issue...

Comment: well at the moment its just a blank project. would be the same as a hello world project. Will try all that and get back to you

Comment: Cool - let me know how you get on.

Comment: Followed that exactly, got the same errors (Excluding the classpath)

Comment: yeah its pretty much the exact same.

Comment: Hmm - where is SecondBirthday coming from, it is not a plugin is it?